# Whats the optimum configuration for Bloom Filter?

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to figure out the optimal configuration for Bloomfilter. What should be bloomfilter value?.
Is there any formula to figure out the optimum number based on nodes, data size, read/write frequency?

Answer (score 1):

Appropriate Bloom Filter settings are more dependent upon memory than anything else.  A low Bloom Filter setting reduces the chance of false positive at the expense of requiring more memory.

For Datastax's explanation, see http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/operations/tuning#tuning-bloomfiltershttp://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/operations/tuning#tuning-bloomfilters

To understand what's actually going on behind the scenes I recommend the following book by my former prof: http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/book.pdf#page=154